One Wi-Fi network is suddenly off the internet (Ubuntu 24.10)
One Wi-Fi network that I always use suddenly stopped working in the middle of my daily work.

It just shows a Wi-Fi icon with a question mark in it instead of signal strength. If I connect to it, there is no internet. And I still can connect to other networks and the internet works fine.
That network works on other devices without any issue, no changes in router settings, etc. It's even working on that specific machine if I boot the system from a live USB.
I tried restarting / reinstalling NetworkManager, forgetting that network in Ubuntu GUI, removed all configs of that network in /etc/, flushed IP tables, etc.
